# How does instanceof work across class changes/NPM versions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, instanceof

Say I have the following code.

```
const myNPMPackage = require("myNPMPackage");
const checkIfUserPackage = require("checkIfUserPackage");

const userObj = {"name": {"first": "Joe", "last": "Smith"}};
const user = new myNPMPackage.User(userObj);
checkIfUserPackage.checkIfUser(user); // true
checkIfUserPackage.checkIfUser(userObj); // false

// Then in the `checkIfUserPackage` package it has the following code, and also has `myNPMPackage` as a dependency of `checkIfUserPackage`
const myNPMPackage = require("myNPMPackage");
module.exports.checkIfUser = (user) => user instanceof myNPMPackage.User;
```

This code works perfectly and as expected.

My question is, what happens if `myNPMPackage` makes an update to that `User` class, and the `myNPMPackage` version that I'm using in my code is a different version than the `myNPMPackage` version that `checkIfUserPackage` is using?

Obviously in that case it's possible that the `myNPMPackage.User` class will be different in my project than it is in `checkIfUserPackage`. But I still want that `checkIfUser` method to return true.

Under the hood, how does `instanceof` work between NPM package versions?

If this will cause problems across versions, is there any work arounds to ensure that even across different versions that the `instanceof` will return the expected result?

Comment: I would ask why you need to perform this check in the first place?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Probably more of a safety thing more than anything. I have it setup to throw a custom error if you don't pass in the correct instance type, as opposed to it throwing a JS error. That way it's easier to pinpoint what the problem is if a mistake is made. Which happened to me in the past, so I adjusted to the code to be more defensive.

Comment: No, `instanceof` does not work between two different classes.